# Is it possible to use a tikzpicture as background in a beamer presentation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, backgrounds, presentations

I'm trying to add a .tikz format file as background in a beamer presentation slide, but it seems to work with only .png, .jpg, .pdf files:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background.jpg}}
```

Comment: You can compile the TikZ figure within a `standalone` class and obtain a .pdf which can be used with `\setbeamertemplate`.  Another solution could be to draw the tikz picture on every frame, in this case you can use absolute coordinates (`current page`, `overlay`, `remember picture`) to place it.

Comment: You can just add a `tikzpicture`. Try e.g. `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[left color=blue,right color=red] (0,0) rectangle
(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}

\end{frame}
\end{document}`. That is, you do not need anything special.

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger'scat, it worked; please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

One may just add a `tikzpicture` instead of `\includegraphics`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[left color=blue,right color=red] (0,0) rectangle(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \frametitle{\textcolor{white}{A slide with a Ti\emph{k}Z picture in the back}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: I like this plain beamer!

Answer (score 6):

Anything that can be typeset can be set as a slide background, using `\setbeamertemplate{background}{...}`. As the Ti*k*Z background graphics will be repeated on every slide, it is saved in an `xsavebox`first. This may save some file size of the final PDF output, especially for complicated graphics and many slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{\xusebox{graphics for bg}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xlrbox}{graphics for bg}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, color=black!30}]
  \node [anchor=south west] at (0,0) {A};
  \node [anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth,0) {B};
  \node [anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth,\paperheight) {C};
  \node [anchor=north west] at (0,\paperheight) {D};
  \node [rotate=30] at (0.5\paperwidth,0.5\paperheight) {\Huge background};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{xlrbox}

\begin{frame}
Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Slide 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Slide 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]